# Why does Silverlight for Windows Phone throw an exception when deriving a class from Dictionary<TKey, TValue> where the key parameter is an enum?

Tags: silverlight, exception, dictionary, enums, windows-phone-7

I'm really curious about the lower level reason for this restriction, documented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(VS.95).aspx

Comment: Not sure any of the WP7/Silverlight team hang out here in SO, but this sounds like a question for them.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that is strange...

> **Platform Notes**
>
> **Silverlight for Windows Phone:**
>
> An exception is thrown when deriving
>   a class from **Dictionary** where the
>   *TKey* parameter is an enumeration.

I do that all the time in non-WP7 apps!

Maybe related to the way enums get special treatment or the "Caution" added here in July:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum(VS.95).aspx

> You should never create an enumeration type whose underlying type is non-integral. Although you can create such a type by using reflection, method calls that use the resulting type are unreliable and may also throw additional exceptions.